# Gmap.net Convert route to points

Tags: c#, vb.net, gmap.net

I have a [route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lK1w.png) from point: A to point B.

I would like convert my route to points list (every 3 meters).
Can it possibility in GMap.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. I use List of Point (LatLng) and I have list full list of points.

```
       ''Create my route

       Dim sta As New PointLatLng(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
        Dim sto As New PointLatLng(TextBox4.Text, TextBox3.Text)
        Dim route As MapRoute = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap.GetRoute(sta, sto, False, False, 13)
        Dim rs As New GMapRoute(route.Points, "Route1")
        Dim iOvrL As New GMapOverlay
        iOvrL.Routes.Add(rs)
        GMapa.Overlays.Add(iOvrL)

''GET POINTS
        For Each point As PointLatLng In rs.Points
            Dim pointx As String = point.Lat.ToString()
            Dim pointy As String = point.Lng.ToString()
        Next
```